# Is such modification allowed by GPL? Which licences allow this which not?

Tags: java, licensing, open-source, gpl

Assume that I have **library X** which contains **class A** with **method b** and that library X is realeased under **GPL licence**.

```
public class A {
  public void b() {
     // this is an example of b method's body. But assume that the body of method b 
     // is very complex
     System.out.println("operation a");
     System.out.println("operation b");
     System.out.prinltn("operation c");
   }    
}
```

Assume that I am using library X and that I need a behaviour similar to the behaviour of  the method b but with one addtition which I cannot achieve by simple extension of class A and overriding some of theirs methods.

**The first question is:** May I extend class A and override method b in shown below way and is it really still allowed by the GPL licence.

```
public class AExt extends A {
  public void b() {
     // this is an example of b method's body. But assume that the body of method b 
     // is very complex
     System.out.println("operation a");
     System.out.println("operation b");
     doOperationINeed();
     System.out.prinltn("operation c");
   }    
}
```

**The 2nd question is:** Which from the common used opensource licences allow such extension and which do not?

Answer (score 4):

Open Source licenses, and even a lot of propriety closed source licenses will allow you to make a change like that.  However, they all put **additional constraints on what you can then do with the software afterwards**.

If you want to distribute the modified code, you need to read through and understand all the license terms that you received with the original code.

In the case of the (L)GPL, you must follow the terms of the (L)GPL in distributing derived code bases, which will include crediting the original author and protecting all the rights in the (L)GPL that your users must also receive for your code changes too.

Comment: I see. In this case about which I am asking the library X is under LGPL and the product which is planned to use it is a commmercial one.

Comment: Distributing a modified version of a LGPL project is (I believe) identical to distributing a modified GPL project.